# Get access to source name, line number and variable name using autoexp.dat within $ADDIN function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, autoexp.dat

Like described here: [MSDN article about autoexp.dat and $ADDIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fwk67y3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), I create DLL with function that represents data of my type at debugging.

This function in my library allows that:

```
HRESULT WINAPI CustomViewer(
DWORD dwAddress,       // low 32-bits of address
DEBUGHELPER *pHelper,  // callback pointer to access helper functions
int nBase,             // decimal or hex
BOOL bIgnore,          // not used
char *pResult,         // where the result needs to go
size_t max,            // how large the above buffer is
DWORD dwReserved       // always pass zero
)
```

Is it possible somehow to get not just address of variable, but also it's name, maybe source file and line where debugger is at the moment it calls this function?